# mysql query browser edit button disabled

Tags: mysql, sql

Has anyone had this problem? I deleted a column in the table editor and then went back to MySql Query Browser but the edit button was disabled. Can't seem to figure it out and I hate MySql's forum format so i decided to ask here. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh i think i found out why...

I deleted the primary key..

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?108,15476,82111

Comment: Yes...if you delete the only unique column on a table mysql admin will not what to "update by".

Comment: The linked forum post simply says that the "Edit" button is disabled when the table has no primary key.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, although I had a primary key in the table. It took me quite a while to figure out that the problem was the name of the table! It was "joinclub_requests". Apparently, if the name starts with "join", the Query Browser thinks its a join table and disables the edit button.